# Is there a "page rendering completed" event in GWT?

Tags: gwt, layout, rendering

I have a widget (third-party) that calculates his size depending on the size of parent element. It does not work because the size of parent element is 0 during the creating of the widget. It works only if I call the onResize() method explicitly when the page was completely loaded. Calling onResize() in Scheduler.scheduleDeferred does not help because it is calling before the page was rendered.
How can I recognize that the page is completely rendered and immediately call onResize?

Answer (score 0):

[`Scheduler.get().scheduleEntry(Scheduler.RepeatingCommand)`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.3/com/google/gwt/core/client/Scheduler.html#scheduleEntry%28com.google.gwt.core.client.Scheduler.RepeatingCommand%29) might be what you're looking for.